# Merge columns in Python/Pandas of Dataframe1 from Dataframe2 only if specific column contains at least one of the words of the other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, data-munging

Consider the Dataframes:

Employees:

```
Employee    City

Ernest      Tel Aviv
Merry       New York
Mason       Cairo
```

Clients:

```
Client  Words

Ernest  New vacuum Tel
Mason   Tel Aviv is so pretty
Merry   Halo! I live in the city York
```

I'm trying to merge columns in Pandas of Dataframe1 (`Employees`) from Dataframe2 (`Clients`) only if one of the words in column `City` (of `Employees`) is contained in column `Words` of `Clients`.

The desired result should be as follows:

```
Employee    City        Words

Ernest      Tel Aviv    New vacuum Tel
Merry       New York    Halo! I live in the city York
```

Tried something like this

import pandas as pd

```
data1 = pd.read_csv('..........csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('..........csv')

output = pd.merge(data1, data2, left_on=  ['City', 'column1'],
                   right_on= ['Words', 'column1'], 
                   how = 'inner')
```

But didn't really boiled down to something.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- splits **City** and **Words** columns into a **list** then `explode()` to generate rows
- you can now `merge()` to get required output

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data1 = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO("""Employee    City
Ernest      Tel Aviv
Merry       New York
Mason       Cairo"""),sep="\s\s+",engine="python",)

data2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Client  Words
Ernest  New vacuum Tel
Mason   Tel Aviv is so pretty
Merry   Halo! I live in the city York"""),sep="\s\s+",engine="python",)

data1.assign(tokens=data1["City"].str.split(" ")).explode("tokens").merge(
    data2.assign(tokens=data2["Words"].str.split(" ")).explode("tokens"),
    left_on=["Employee", "tokens"],
    right_on=["Client", "tokens"],
).drop(columns="tokens").drop_duplicates()
```

|  | Employee | City | Client | Words |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Ernest | Tel Aviv | Ernest | New vacuum Tel |
| 1 | Merry | New York | Merry | Halo! I live in the city York |

Answer (score 1):

Complicated join;

#Extract last word in Client's Words

```
 Clients['joinword']=Clients['Words'].str.extract("(\w+$)")
```

#Make it a search word  separated by `|` for `or`

```
 s='|'.join(Clients['joinword'].to_list())
```

#Find `s` in Employees City

```
Employees['joinword']=Employees['City'].str.findall(f'{s}').str[0]
```

#Now merge as follows

```
 pd.merge(Employees,Clients, right_on=['Client','joinword'],left_on=['Employee','joinword'], how='inner')

Employee      City joinword  Client                          Words
0   Ernest  Tel Aviv      Tel  Ernest                 New vacuum Tel
1    Merry  New York     York   Merry  Halo! I live in the city York
```